# How to fix DLL Load failed in visual studio code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

when I try to import pygame , I facing an error.

The error shown by visual studio code as following:

```
from pygame.base import * # pylint: disable=wildcard-import; lgtm[py/polluting-import]
Import error: DLL load failed while importing base: The specified procedure could not be found
```

Additional Information:
I have already installed pywin32 and pypiwin32

python version-3.9

visual studio code version-1.51

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the Python you are currently using is the same bit as the installed pygame (both are 64-bit or 32-bit).

It is recommended that you reinstall the module "pygame" in the python3.9 environment: `pip3 install pygame==2.0.0 python==3.9`

I am using python3.9(64), pygame2.0.0:

[image]